# wpf c# change an element in selected tab

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML code like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TabControl Margin="0,53,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="First">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <TextBlock />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Second" >
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <TextBlock />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Third">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <TextBlock />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8,174,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TextBox Height="20.96" Margin="30,9,267,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Using C# in every tabitem there is one textblock
if I type something in textbox, and after that I click the button, and now selected TabItem is "third"
Please help me how to change the textblock in that Selected TabItem now?
**yeah the textbox and button outside from tab.**

Comment: If you click the button, nothing happens - you have no behaviour wired to the button.  Do you want help *making* something happen?

Comment: Also, the content are outside the tabs... so obviously changing the tab, wouldn't change the content.

Comment: Why do you think it's outside? It isn't

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TabControl Margin="0,53,0,0" Name="tabControl">
        <TabItem Header="First">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <TextBlock />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Second" >
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <TextBlock />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Third">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <TextBlock />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8,174,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBox Height="20.96" Margin="30,9,267,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="textBox"/>
</Grid>
```

Backing code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var match = tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().Where(tab => tab.Header.ToString() == textBox.Text).FirstOrDefault();
    if (match != null) match.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Hope I get you right

**Update**
Looks like I didn't understand you from the first time. Here's right backing code for your case:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().Where(tab => tab.IsSelected == true).First().Header = textBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Try code from my answer. It will change Header text of selected tab to current text in your textbox when you hit the button.